# How to $emit data from dynamic form with multiple components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I am working on a app where a user can create task lists. Once created the list will be pulled from the database for the user to work with it and select an appropriate response for each task.

Responses: - Yes or No

Selecting 'No': Enables reasons dropdown to select reason why task is not done - Selecting 'other' option will display custom reason input box.

The user can also add comments to each task and once the form is completed they can submit it.

Because of how dynamic the component that displays each task is, I don't know how to capture the form responses. I have created a `<form>` around the component - which once clicked should submit the form, but I don't know how to get the data from the component.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/form-component-issue-forked-nwtcr?file=/src/components/checklistItem.vue)

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <button @click="toggleComplete">Complete All</button>
  <form @submit.prevent="submitModal">
    <checklist-item
      v-for="taskList in myChecklist.tasks.data"
      :key="taskList.id"
      :taskDetails="taskList"
      :marked="markAll"
    >
    </checklist-item>
    <div class="">
      <button class="" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
import checklistItem from "./components/checklistItem.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    checklistItem,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      markAll: false,
      myChecklist: {
        success: true,
        name: "Checklist 1",
        roomId: 1,
        notes: "Notes about the checklist",
        tasks: {
          data: [
            {
              id: 1,
              name: "Task 1",
              frequency: "D",
              status: null,
              comment: null,
              reason: null,
              updated_at: "2021-08-09",
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              name: "Task 2",
              frequency: "M",
              status: null,
              comment: null,
              reason: null,
              updated_at: "2021-08-09",
            },
            {
              id: 3,
              name: "Task 3",
              frequency: "Y",
              status: null,
              comment: null,
              reason: null,
              updated_at: "2021-08-09",
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleComplete() {
      this.markAll = !this.markAll;
    },
    submitModal() {
      console.log("inside");
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

**ChecklistItem.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="flex justify-center items-center">
    <div
      class="border border-gray-200 w-11/12 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-sm hover:shadow-2xl duration-500 px-2 py-4 my-1"
    >
      <div class="flex flex-col m-auto w-11.5/12">
        <div class="">
          <div class="text-xl font-semibold">
            {{ taskDetails.name }}
          </div>
          <div class="pb-2 sm-pb-0">
            <p>Due: <strong>Today</strong></p>
          </div>
          <!-- Yes Button -->
          <div class="yesClass flex justify-center-0 pb-2">
            <input
              @change="disableSelect()"
              type="radio"
              :checked="marked"
              :name="taskDetails.id"
              :id="taskDetails.id + 'yes'"
              class=""
            />
            <label
              :for="taskDetails.id + 'yes'"
              class="yesClass border text-center border-orange-400 rounded-2xl w-full py-0.5 hover:bg-green-400 hover:text-white hover:border-green-200"
            >
              <span>Yes</span>
            </label>
          </div>
          <!-- No Button -->
          <div class="noClass flex justify-center pb-2">
            <input
              @change="enableSelect()"
              type="radio"
              :name="taskDetails.id"
              :id="taskDetails.id + 'no'"
              class=""
            />
            <label
              :for="taskDetails.id + 'no'"
              class="border text-center border-orange-400 rounded-2xl w-full py-0.5 label-checked:bg-green-200 hover:bg-red-800 hover:text-white hover:border-red-200"
            >
              <span>No</span>
            </label>
          </div>
          <!-- Reason Dropdown -->
          <p>Reason:</p>
          <div class="disabled flex justify-center">
            <br />
            <select
              :disabled="!notCompletedToggle"
              name="reason"
              id="reasons"
              class="w-full mt-1 rounded-lg py-0.5 my-0.5"
              :class="[notCompletedToggle ? 'bg-red-500' : '']"
              ref="selectedItem"
              @change="customEventToggle($event)"
            >
              <option value="reason_1" :selected="!notCompletedToggle">
                Select Reason
              </option>
              <option value="reason_1">Reason 1</option>
              <option value="reason_2">Reason 2</option>
              <option value="reason_3">Reason 3</option>
              <option value="other">Other --></option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div
            class="flex justify-center my-0.5"
            :class="{ hidden: !customReasonToggle }"
          >
            <input
              type="text"
              class="bg-gray-200 w-full rounded-md mt-1 py-0.5"
              v-model="customReason"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="">
          <div class="flex items-end justify-start text-grey">
            <label>Comment:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="flex items-end justify-center">
            <textarea
              type="text"
              class="bg-gray-200 rounded-lg w-full h-16"
            ></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  components: {},
  emits: ["custom-event-toggle"],
  props: ["taskDetails", "marked"],
  data() {
    return {
      notCompletedToggle: false,
      customReasonToggle: false,
      customReason: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    customEventToggle(event) {
      if (event.target.value === "other") {
        this.customReasonToggle = true;
      } else {
        this.customReasonToggle = false;
      }
    },
    disableSelect() {
      this.notCompletedToggle = false;
      this.customReasonToggle = false;
    },
    enableSelect() {
      this.notCompletedToggle = true;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
.yesClass input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: #78be20;
  color: white;
}
.noClass input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: #da291c;
  color: white;
}
</style>
```

Comment: simply emit it then update the model, but you could expand to use slots so checklist-item is simply showing the item values and a component you hook in which gets passed the current item is managing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emit events from inside the `checklist-item` component on each event to set the values inside your `myChecklist.tasks.data` array.

```
methods: {
    updateData(property, value) {
      this.$emit("update-form-data", {
        id: this.taskDetails.id,
        property,
        value,
      });
    },
    customEventToggle(event) {
      this.updateData("reason", event.target.value);
      if (event.target.value === "other") {
        this.customReasonToggle = true;
      } else {
        this.customReasonToggle = false;
      }
    },
    disableSelect() {
      this.updateData("status", "YES");
      this.notCompletedToggle = false;
      this.customReasonToggle = false;
    },
    enableSelect() {
      this.updateData("status", "NO");
      this.notCompletedToggle = true;
    },
    setComment(event) {
      this.updateData("comment", event.target.value);
    },
}
```

Then listen to the event in parent component and update your data array:

```
<checklist-item
      v-for="taskList in myChecklist.tasks.data"
      :key="taskList.id"
      :taskDetails="taskList"
      :marked="markAll"
      @update-form-data="
        this.myChecklist.tasks.data.find((task) => task.id === $event.id)[
          $event.property
        ] = $event.value
      "
```

[Here's your updated sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/form-component-issue-forked-ymxcd?file=/src/App.vue:110-413). Logs data to console on clicking submit.